# Axios error: Cannot read property 'transitional' of undefined

Tags: node.js, server, axios

We have 2 servers running the same NodeJS backend API with same Axios versions - 0.20.0 which we plan to upgrade soon.
ONLY 1 of the servers, sometimes after deploy with github actions starts getting this error on a specific third party API POST request. We do not touch this property anywhere, and this started to be a problem a few months back.

`Cannot read property 'transitional' of undefined`

Anyone had experience with this? Would just upgrading Axios help?

We tried to reproduce this on different servers (API 2, staging and locally) but with no luck.

Comment: I've experienced a similar problem, do you happen to know the lambda runtime version? Its the first line of the log that starts with `INIT_START Runtime Version:`

Comment: @AshokaLella Which log are you referencing to? So I can search for this on the servers.

Comment: it should be the first line in the lambda's log. I was assuming you were using AWS lambda (my bad). But, I don't think it may be related to the environment/runtime. I had the problem in axios-0.21.1 , I stopped seeing the problem after upgrading to axios-0.21.4.

Comment: @AshokaLella we don't use lambdas. I will upgrade and we will see if the error persists. It is good to know what is the cause of the problem in any case...Still, thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like upgrading axios fixes the issue.